# Equivalence of convergence in products of sequences.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\{x_{n}\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and $\{y_{n}\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be two convergent sequences.  I am trying to show that 
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k = 0}^{n} x_{k}y_{n - k} &= \left(\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_{n}\right)\left(\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} y_{n}\right).
\end{align}

I think I just need some fancy application of summation by parts but I haven't quite figured it out yet.

Comment: Split the sum into three parts. In the middle part, both, $x_k$ and $y_{n-k}$, are close to the respective limits.

Comment: By these three parts I'm assuming that you mean the three parts from the summation by parts formula?

Comment: No, I didn't intend to use summation by parts. I think one could also use that, but I'd have to think about how to employ it.

Comment: what three parts were you thinking of?

Comment: $$\sum_{k=0}^n a_k b_{n-k} = \sum_{k=0}^{K-1} a_k b_{n-k} + \sum_{k=K}^{n-K} a_k b_{n-k} + \sum_{k=n-K+1}^n a_k b_{n-k}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} x_n \qquad y = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} y_n $

Then for every $\epsilon>0, \qquad |x_n - x| <\epsilon$ when $n > N_x$.

And $\qquad |y_n - y| <\epsilon$ when $n > N_y$

Let $K = \max(N_x,N_y)$

Then your terms are as Daniel Fischer says,

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^nx_ky_{n-k} = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n+1}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{K-1} x_ky_{n-k}+\sum_{k=K}^{n-K} x_ky_{n-k} \sum_{k=n-K+1}^{n} x_ky_{n-k}\right)$$

The number of terms in the first and last sums are fixed (do not change with $n$). So they drop out as you are dividing by $(n+1)$.

You get
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^nx_ky_{n-k} = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=K}^{n-K} x_ky_{n-k}$$

These terms all satisfy the bound above so in that regime, $x_k y_{n-k} \rightarrow x y + \mathcal{O}(\epsilon)$.
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^nx_ky_{n-k} = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{n-2K}{n+1} ( x y ) = x y$$
As claimed.